# How to convert from Powerpoint to HTML / CSS ? (FOSS)

Tags: html, css, xaml, powerpoint

Someone has mocked up a website using PowerPoint, and I have to convert it to HTML / CSS.

This is not a request to simply embed PowerPoint into the webpages.  This will not be a static HTML site. PHP will generate HTML, and there are a bunch of forms for the user to submit information.

Is there a conversion tool, or a series of conversion hoops that I can jump through?
I'd much rather have the styles in CSS than inline in the HTML.

Comment: A web site mockup in _PowerPoint‽_

Comment: +1 But when all you have is a hammer .... look, some folks create text documents in Excel ... anyhoo, that's what I am given (that and an incerdibly short amount of time) ... what would you do (if it was your mom, who needed the site for granny's funeral? i.e., it has to be done and there's no way out)

Comment: I would re-write it by hand in HTML and CSS

Comment: Quickest way: I would read [existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=embed+powerpoint+on+web+page), such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855/embed-powerpoint-into-html). The Right Way: what @Petah said.

Comment: Sorry, Matt, but I quite clearly stated that I ****do not*** want embed PowerPoint into HTML, which is all that your comment discuses.

Comment: Of course, nowadays, questions like this should be asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Nowadays, I would ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: We all followed your journey for over a decade, so I think you owe it to the world to let us know what your outcome was

Comment: I accepted an answer 11 years ago. And have not thought of the topic since. Hopefully the answer helped you? If not, good luck with your new question :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I'm guessing you're not the best with web design hardcode, your options are:

Go into powerpoint, and use the 'Save For Web' button. It won't be perfect, you'll probably have to tweak some stuff, but you could make it look right with much less coding knowledge then the normal site.

[image]

OR: Make a flash site and embed the powerpoint into the flash, if you're flash savvy.

OR: Here's a poweproint conversion tool if your powerpoint if you don't want to code at all: http://www.pptools.com/ppt2html/index.html
I'm not sure how well it works, you'll probably just end up frustrated and you'll have to code some anyway.

Option #1 is good, and it will require very little actual coding, just fixing the thing powerpoint does wrong.

Option #3, flash ewww.

Option #4 I haven't tried it, but you sure can if you're feeling up to it, probably won't be too fast or customizable.

But overall, the best bet is going to be look at it with your eyes and convert it using your knowledge of code and w3fools.com, err, oops, http://www.w3schools.com/ as a resource.

Comment: +1 .. and no offence taken :-)   Not having PP (which I omitted to mention), I didn't know that it had an export to HTML function (someone mentioned XAML in passing).  If so, expect either a web paeg with lots of CSS in the header (hopefully easy to convert) or styles on each HTML element (which is what I fear & why I ask for help) ...

Comment: Lots of css in the header is fine. Just copy it into a style.css file and <link> it. Remove lines one by one to find that which you do not need. Styles on each html element would be bad, you'd have to go by each element one by one and make selectors and combine, it would take a few hours, but it could be done.

Like I said, you should need to tweak it a bit, pp is far from perfect.

Comment: +1 hanks, Jackson, it looks like I will be going with option #1. I don't mind fine tuning (but I do remember years ago looking at the "HTML" produced by MS word ... shudder. Hopefully it's gotten better - or I have).   With any luck a few global edits will take care of 80% or more of it, leaving just a few hours of manual tweaking.

Comment: Save As Web Page does not exist on PowerPoint 2010.  See my answer here for PowerPoint 2010.

Comment: Excuse me, there is [Codeacademy](codeacademy.com) and [Mozilla Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn).

Answer (score 8):

The "Save As Webpage" option no longer exists on PowerPoint 2010 and later.

Microsoft has provided [a workaround](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980553), summarized as, "use the `ppSaveAsHTML` argument for the `*.htm` file format."

- In PowerPoint 2010, open the presentation that you want to export to HTML.
- Press Alt+F11, this opens VB for Apps.
- Press Ctrl+G, this opens the Immediate pane.
- In the Immediate pane, type the following, and then press the `Enter` key:

  `ActivePresentation.SaveAs "<Drive>:\users\<username>\desktop\<filename>.htm", ppSaveAsHTML, msoFalse`

To save by using the Single File Web Page (`*.mht`;`*.mhtml`) file format, replace `htm` at the end of the file name with `mht`, and replace `ppSaveAsHTML` with `ppSaveAsWebArchive`.

Comment: For the benefit of searchers - this no longer works in 2013. Microsofts suggestion is to save it as a PDF or PPT and put it on SkyDrive - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/14fe0e03-3fce-4775-933d-2fe4da5accde/powerpoint-2013-save-as-web-page-feature-missing

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, I don't think the PPTools PPT2HTML add-in will give the needed results.  I wrote it, so I suppose I can answer as authoritatively as anyone. ;-)

It'll give you an image of the original PPT slide, optionally with an image map that preserves the links and action settings if any.

And it could be used to extract the title, body and any other text in a fairly predictable way, and could even insert any HTML/CSS code you like around each of these bits of text, but unless the slide/slides are fairly simple examples of stock PPT slides, that might not be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using PowerPoint 2016. I used [this site](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/ppt-to-html/) to convert my PowerPoint to an HTML file. I got the CSS, HTML, JavaScript all in one HTML file.

Comment: +1.  Zamzar online service is not a free-software solution, but it **is the only solution here that really works** fine in nowadays (2017+).

Answer (score 1):

The best i found (for developers) is PowerPoint to Html5 SDK. It convert powerpoint to html including video and audio with amazing player API. Very easy to customize (player template can be customized). Quality is also good: [try it](http://conaito.com/products/powerpoint-to-html5-sdk.aspx)

Comment: Agree that Html5SDK is quite good. Is it possible to create a server that Html5SDK is installed on, and a web service to convert from ppt to html. I mean in this case, does the sdk charge a lot?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the converion tool html5point? They have a demo on the site as in convertio. But there is a watermark on the output.

https://www.digitalofficepro.com/powerpoint/powerpoint-to-html5-converter.html

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to :

1. Export your PowerPoint presentation to a .pdf document with :

- File
- Export
- Create PDF

2. Convert your pdf document to an .html file with :

- Any free website you will find by googling "pdf to html"
- Adobe, ...

Answer (score -1):

By far the easiest way to convert your PPT to HTML5 format is to use iSpring Converter Pro. Check it out here: http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ppt-to-html

Comment: This app is used to embed PowerPoint into the HTML5 webpages. But OP says: *"This is not a request to simply embed PowerPoint into the webpages."*

Comment: Using this app we can't convert PPT to HTML.