# power point to html 5

Tags: html, point

I'm looking for a tool/solution that would allow me to convert a power point presentation into a fully html5 website. I've seen solutions like iSpring and html5point which just make each slide as an img or iSpring whihc is good for simple slides. In my case the slides contain  graphics and shapes (no animation or video though). Any adivce ?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274218/how-to-convert-from-powerpoint-to-html-css-foss

Comment: Most eLearing packages do this these days, even for very complex slides (video, audio, animation, triggers, etc.). Adobe Captivate, iSpring Pro, Articulate Presenter '13 (when it comes out), Lectora Inspire. Again, pretty common nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any of the solutions you mention, but the last time I had to do this I found it easiest to export (Save As ...) the .ppt as a single webpage and then copy and paste chunks of it into a template I had created previously.