# Embed Powerpoints dynamically on my Website for students and theachers

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, powerpoint

I need to embed the powerpoints that the theachers had uploaded to my website.

**Things that i've tried:**

1. Embed with  using view.officeapps.live.com

   The problem with this is that the powerpoints shown on the iframe are all on stream so if someone whants to  the powerpoint on the same the powerpoint on the same time on differnt slides its impossible.
2. Use PhpPowerpoint API

   I can´t embed powerpoints with this API I've tried almost everything to get it to work but it seems that its impossible for me.

Heres the code of my PhpPowerpoint

```
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\PhpPresentation;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Color;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Shape\MemoryDrawing;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Fill;

require_once 'PhpPresentation/src/PhpPresentation/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Autoloader::register();

require_once 'Common/src/Common/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\Common\Autoloader::register();

$pptReader = IOFactory::createReader('PowerPoint2007');
$oPHPPresentation = $pptReader->load('http://webitcloud.net/PW/1617/weduc/Teste.pptx');

$oTree = new PhpPptTree($oPHPPresentation);
echo $oTree->display();

?>
```

The Powerpoint that i am trying to embed is Tetste.pptx.
All paths are correct and the error that appers is the following:

'Could not open http://webitcloud.net/PW/1617/weduc/Teste.pptx for reading! File does not exist.' in /home/webitcloud/public_html/PW/1617/weduc/PhpPresentation/src/PhpPresentation/Reader/PowerPoint2007.php:97

**Things that could help me**

3. Some kind of API similar to PhpPowerpoint that lets me embend my pptx dynamically.
4. Some code that converts the powerpoints that the Teachers had uploaded previously into html format.

   Thanks in advance,

   Afonso Martinho.

Comment: I don't understand point 1. Can you please clarify?

Comment: i dont want to stream the powerpoint, i just want to embed it on my website so everyone can see it not on stream. 

view.officeapps.live.com streams the pptx.

Comment: If you want help with PhpPowerpoint, you should provide your code and your error log. If you want recommendations for APIs, you're better off googling it then asking here!

Comment: I've posted my code and errors

Comment: You should use `file_get_contents()` first to load the .pptx file onto your server: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: like this?

$powerpoint = file_get_contents('http://webitcloud.net/PW/1617/weduc/Teste.pptx');

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6274218/266535

Comment: @Afonso no like this: `file_get_contents('http://webitcloud.net/PW/1617/weduc/Teste.pptx')`

Comment: i should put that inside the load function or before everything?

Comment: If you want to embed it on your own website, you might need it to be HTML not pptx.  Your site does not have code to render PowerPoint docs.  See @styfle's link above

Comment: is there a code or API that converts pptx into HTML dynamically?