# How do I implement PDF/ PPT viewing facilty in my website?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, browser

Are there **any open source/free tools using which I can implement ppt/ pdf viewing facility** in my website ?

The documents are stored on my own database server & external links as well.

Comment: Look at this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855/embed-powerpoint-into-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "online pdf editor" and several companies will show up.  Some of them sell PDF libraries to do what you want.

A roll-it-yourself solution would be to start with Ghostscript for PDFs, and Office for PPTs, and use them to emit jpg or png files.