# Embed a Powerpoint in a Web Page

Tags: html, powerpoint

Is there any way to embed a PowerPoint slide show in an HTML page using just the standard tags etc? I tried using a iframe, but that just results in the PowerPoint being downloaded.

```
<iframe src="Chapter1.pptx">Your browser does not support.</iframe>
```

I am looking for a way to show the slide show using only standard stuff. I realize I could use google docs or flash or something, but I'd rather have a simple implementation.

Does the web just not know how to process a PowerPoint presentation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embed Powerpoint into HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855/embed-powerpoint-into-html)

Comment: I said I do not want to use google docs.

Comment: It lists other possible solutions, look at the answers below the accepted one.

Comment: I saw ones about Flash and other applications, but I'll look deeper some more.

Comment: Google docs _is_ the simple implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have decided to take a hack route and upload the powerpoint onto YouTube and then just include the youtube video in the iframe.

```
<iframe height="375" width="600" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/assignedId"></iframe>
```

I know, it's cheap, but it's also easy.

### EDIT

I eventually checked my page as XHTML Strict, which does not support the `<iframe>` tag. So I used the `object` tag instead.

```
<object data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/assignedId">
```

Comment: Hey, please give me solution for without putting ppt on the drive and take from the server then how do they do it?

Answer (score 74):

Plain and simple...this is the best method to embed any Microsoft or Adobe file into a HTML website.

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=[https://www.your_website/file_name.pptx]' width='100%' height='600px' frameborder='0'>
```

Comment: I wonder why the hell your answer doesn't get more upvotes. It's the closest one to the original intention of the asker.

Comment: This answer won't work for presentations on an internal website.

Comment: <iframe width="100%" height="630" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=your_file&embedded=true" ></iframe>

Comment: JS
var url = encodeURIComponent(originalURl);
HTML:
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=${url}' width='100%' height='600px' frameborder='0'>

Comment: There is a size limit of 10MB.

Comment: As of 2022, I can't get the above answer to work.  I've updated the url to a real deck in the github sharepoint that I uploaded.  I assume the view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed... isn't there any more.

Comment: This is actually working even today. But need some help on how we can jump into preview mode directly for pptx with configurable slide change duration

Comment: @AlexisCabreraMondeja

Comment: @Anil can you please help on the above question

Comment: AFAICT this method works, but has the limitation that it does not work with "file:///" type urls for content hosted on the local filesystem.  ie. `src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=[file:///somefile.pptx]` doesn't work.  Can anyone prove me wrong?

Answer (score 15):

Just to update this question - as there is a new way to embed Powerpoints in a web page. If you have an account on [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com), do the following using Powerpoint Online (accessing Powerpoint via the browser) to embed a Powerpoint:

1. Click 'File', then 'Share', then 'Embed' [image: Share Powerpoint]
2. Click the 'Generate' button to generate HTML code to be embedded [image: Generate HTML]
3. Copy the 'Embed Code' and paste it in the HTML of a website [image: Copy Embed Code]

Comment: this was unexpectedly easy!

Comment: Hey, please give me solution for without putting ppt on the drive and take from the server then how do they do it?

Comment: requires viewers to have a microsoft account. not a good solution for a public website.

Answer (score 5):

Web browsers don't understand power point, but there are solutions besides Flash.

You could export it to HTML or a PDF.  Or you could also upload to site like [slideshare](http://slideshare.net) and make use of their players which are built for this problem.

Comment: +1, thanks for the help. I have decided to use YouTube (see answer). Thanks again. ^_^

Comment: Hey, please give me solution for without putting ppt on the drive and take from the server then how do they do it?

Answer (score 3):

I tried answer posted by Shane, which looks exactly right and how MS used to have PPT viewing online earlier but it didn't worked for me. After doing some research I found out that the link has changed a bit.

So use:
https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/**view.aspx** *instead of* https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/**embed.aspx**

Example:

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=[https://www.your_website/file_name.pptx]' width='100%' height='600px' frameborder='0'>
```

Note: Link to PPT need to be publicly accessible.

Comment: I like more google docs viewer works with docs, pptx, pdf, etc. <iframe  width="100%" height="630" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=your_file&embedded=true" ></iframe>

Comment: Animations and effects present in a PPT won't work with google docs viewers.

Comment: But you can use "Open With" and use Google presentations App.

Comment: I'm not sure if that can be done directly via a link like we can with MS.
Also I believe to use Google Slides user need to be signed in with an Google account.

Answer (score 2):

Use Microsoft skydrive, upload your power point to this site and use this code

where

http://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=20f065afc1acdb2e&page=view&resid=20F065AFC1ACDB2E!723&parid=20F065AFC1ACDB2E!719 is the URL of the powerpoint  file.

You have to replace  SD20F065AFC1ACDB2E!723 for your own string of the corresponding URL

Comment: <iframe src="http://r.office.microsoft.com/r/rlidPowerPointEmbed?p1=1&p2=1&p3=SD20F065AFC1ACDB2E!723&p4=&kip=1" width="402" height="327" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Comment: Look the code of this site, http://crc.tc/powerpointDemo.html and replace SD20F065AFC1ACDB2E!723 with your own power point skidrive URL identifier

Answer (score 1):

Upload a PowerPoint document on your Google Drive and then 'Share' it with everyone (make it public):
[Sharing your pptx doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gp4R.png)

Then, go to File > Publish to the web > hit the publish button.

Go to Embed and copy the embed code and paste it to your web page

[Copy embed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6en1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Works Best for me.

1. Goto [MS View Office Documents Online Page](https://products.office.com/en/office-online/view-office-documents-online)
2. [Enter link to PPT file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w7mC.png) 
   **Note:** This link should be publicly Accessible
3. Click on Create URL.
4. [Link to view office documents online will be generated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aVec.png)
5. Paste this link to any webpage or as iframe src attribute.

You are all set!! :)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do this by saving the PPT as an mp4 (Save As > MPEG-4 Video (*.mp4)) and then using the video tag.

```
<video controls autoplay preload="none" style="width:1000px;">
<source src="/_dev/power_point/m11983.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<p>Your browser does not support HTML5 Video.</p>
</video>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Google slides you could easily publish it on the web and also embed the slide in an iframe.

Go to google slides -> file-> sharing -> embed and copy the code

[image]

and then in your HTML file use the below code to show slides in fullscreen mode.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/journey.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <!-- show slides in html web page -->
    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PAxxxxxCX-xxxxxxxx-_GuZImZqRUxxxxxxxxxx/embed?start=true&loop=false&delayms=3000" frameborder="0" width="1440" height="839" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

why not use prezi, I just use it in my work, very easy and useful.

[image]