# How to host functional PowerPoint on IIS host

Tags: iis, embed, powerpoint, host

I'm trying to put a PowerPoint on a page on my server. I am able to use Iframes if need be, but currently, if a user opens a page with a PowerPoint, either through the page itself or through an Iframe, the PowerPoint prompts the user through the browser to 'save' or to 'open'. 
It is important to host this on our servers internally as we can't have many material at all available to the public. This rules out using 'OneDrive' or 'PowerPoint Online' as the material will be accessible to anyone who knows the link. If Microsoft would put a Password Protection this would become a solution, but you can not place a password on material you put on your OneDrive. 
It is also important to keep functionality of the PowerPoint. This rules out 'GoogleDocs' because if you open your PowerPoint document using GoogleDocs, it becomes a simple carousel. Menu's become dysfunctional. 
I have read the following pages but they offer methods that are not suitable.

[Embed a Powerpoint in a Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101080/embed-a-powerpoint-in-a-web-page)

[Embed a PowerPoint presentation into HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855/embed-a-powerpoint-presentation-into-html)

Comment: I am open to suggestions on tools. It appears that many people are doing conversions to either ShockWave File (swf) or Silverlight. I'm going to trial out some software but again, would like to maintain the highest level of interactivity for e-Learning style. I'll provide updates on what is trialed and tested and the avenue taken.

Comment: I would read my Office license very carefully before going down this road.  It seems your solution would involve allowing multiple users access to a single instance of PowerPoint.  That wouldn't be legal.  And apart from the legality of it, you can only have one concurrent instance of PPT at a time, so unless you plan to serialize your users, making them wait in line for access to the copy of PPT on the server, it's not going to work.  You might look into multiple licensed copies of PPT running on a terminal server setup.  MS does allow this.