# Cannot display word and presentation document in webpage using object tag

Tags: html, css, object, embed

I want to display word,presentation and pdf documents in objects tag the pdf documents are displaying properly but the when i try to display ppt or doc file 
then no content get displayed and the file simply starts downloading here is my code:

```
<object src="g6ocz4s5khohmkjhqytk_1442355058.docx"><embed src="g6ocz4s5khohmkjhqytk_1442355058.docx" width="100%" height="800"></embed></object>
```

Comment: Does it display a plugin is needed to display this content

Comment: @Transformer: yes it shows that this plugin is not supported both in chrome and firefox browser, is there any other way of achieving this functionality.

Comment: yes i think iframe can do that

Comment: @Transformer: if i'm using iframe it does not show anything and it simply download the file.

Comment: yes i just checked now

Comment: i will do some research for you so check later maybe the next 5 hours

Comment: OK Please check and give me some solution.

Comment: I found something i will post it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103460/discussion-between-user3653474-and-transformer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<iframe src="//www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/key/32eYzbM5zKKsld" width="668" height="714" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" style="border:1px solid #CCC; border-width:1px; margin-bottom:5px; max-width: 100%;" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
```

Hands down, the easiest way to share a PowerPoint presentation on your website is through a free service like [SlideShare.net](http://www.slideshare.net/). Think of it as something like YouTube for slide shows.

Upload your PPT, PPS, or even PDF files to SlideShare and they're converted into shared media. Copy a snippet of code to embed your presentation directly in your own web page (or simply link to your presentation page on SlideShare’s hosting service) and select the level of privacy you want for each file.

One notable advantage here is that viewers can choose to watch your presentation in full-screen format — a very useful feature if you have fine-detailed images or on-screen text you don't want your viewers to miss. You can even choose to sync the slideshow with an uploaded audio file to create an easy screencast. Comment and tag functions are included on the SlideShare site, so your organization might even benefit from the social networking aspect of the service.

But what if your organization would prefer to keep all your files on your own web space, rather than relying on a third-party service? No problem; there are several more options for getting PowerPoint onto the Web.

I got this from this link http://www.wildapricot.com/blogs/newsblog/2008/07/07/4-ways-to-put-a-powerpoint-presentation-on-your-web-site

go to the link http://SlideShare.net

register and login its free

click on upload and upload any document you want, set the privacy to public if you want to embed it in your site. then save.
After save click on share button. Highlight the iframe code only from embed option shown
e.g try this my own, i used it in testing what i saw in the blog i gave you

```
<iframe src="//www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/key/32eYzbM5zKKsld" width="668" height="714" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" style="border:1px solid #CCC; border-width:1px; margin-bottom:5px; max-width: 100%;" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
```

or

you can still check the accepted answer of [Embed a Powerpoint in a Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101080/embed-a-powerpoint-in-a-web-page). But mine i tested it and it works. so choose

Comment: Thanks Transformer for your answer, i am using <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://myweb/iq.pptx&embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe> google docs. This is working fine, i have to pass server url to url parameter then it is working but if i pass local file url it is not able to find the file. Any idea how to give local file url.

Comment: yeah but i will get back to you on that

Comment: I found out that,  It would be a security vulnerability if the client could request local file system files. Browsers aren't allowed to access the local file system unless you're accessing a local html page. so you really need to access a file you have to have it inside your server, thats why only the server url is working