# inserting windows app in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to insert several windows application (powerpoint, photoshop and text editor) in a web page just for viewing.

I don't know how to start

Can I get some indications please

Comment: Perhaps try a google search for "embed powerpoint in webpage" etc. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101080/embed-a-powerpoint-in-a-web-page

Comment: My first thought is `<canvas>`, Web Sockets, and proxying VNC over Web Sockets. No idea if it would work, it is decidedly non-trivial.

Comment: @mplungjan — That's a powerpoint *slide show*, which isn't the same as embedding the whole application.

Comment: I think that I need to embed applications unfortunately if it was just a matter of text editors slide shows it would have been easier 
To be more precise i need to incorporate 4 application interfaces and a slide show to explain the progress of an academic tutorial

Comment: @othmane.z — Take screenshots.

Comment: @Quentin don't you think that video screenshots would be heavy to handle ?
I think that I got the most complicated project indeed... :(

Comment: @othmane.z — Compared to what you are trying? No.

Comment: in terms of bandwidth ?

Comment: @othmane.z — In terms of everything

Comment: @Quentin OK thanks a lot Bro

Answer (score -1):

Some applications have a port to the webbrowser ( most of the time trough a plugin ). This is per application different, and they have different "code" to embed them in the browser.

In your question you list 3 applications:

- **Powerpoint** has a powerpoint viewer plugin. As far I know the editor has no port to the webbrowser
- **Photoshop** does not support emabeding in any way.
- **Text Editor** There are some text editors that have this option, you can look in to Google Docs.

Comment: these apps are just a starting point of the web plateform, and I think that there would be some measure devices that come with there own apps to incorporate too and I don't think that there would be a plugin for them...

Comment: What is it exectly what you trying to achieve? Because a webbrowser is not made to run windows applications.

Comment: ok I will be more precise and I will try to explain another use for the plateform for example
We do have some electronic tutorials and we don't have enough devices for all student and we want to get eal time video captures of the mesuring devices so that all student can follow the tutorial at the same time
I need to program a web page where I'll put all those captures

Comment: The students won't interact with those applications they will just retrieve measures

Comment: Well if we talk about "real time" you can choose a livestream service and embed this in your website ( youtube is a good option, so you can store the video's directly for later use ). There is no need / way to insert an complete application in your webpage.

Comment: Do you think that i can capture several windows and stream them in the same time ?

Comment: Yeah, you could stream your whole ( or multiple ) screens. It might be worth to google OBS ( https://obsproject.com/ )