# Show PowerPoint in Web

Tags: c#, html, file, io

How to show a PowerPoint file in web using C#? I want to get file from a URL then do some ways to show this PowerPoint in HTML.
I do not want to use drive in my project. 
Help me ! Thanks

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101080/embed-a-powerpoint-in-a-web-page

Comment: i mean when you use code C#, 1 user input files in my system and this system do somethings to other users can see the out put, not only one file

Comment: Please show us what you have coded so far and explain where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: i do not want to use drive in my project !

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a simple way to do this as well recently and found this answer by @wclear:

> just to update this question - as there is a new way to embed
>   Powerpoints in a web page. If you have an account on OneDrive, do the
>   following using Powerpoint Online (accessing Powerpoint via the
>   browser) to embed a Powerpoint:
>
> Click 'File', then 'Share', then 'Embed'  [image] Click the 'Generate' button to generate HTML
>   code to be embedded 
>   [image]
>   Copy the 'Embed Code' and paste it in the HTML of a website 
>    [image]

Comment: i do not want to use drive in my project !