# Insert powerpoint on web

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to make a powerpoint viewer on WEB? This is the ouput I want to achieve. In my page there is a insert file then the file is powerpoint presentation . How can I display the presentation I inserted on my page? I searched about this but I can't get useful ideas.

Comment: for your reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/7101080/6191987](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7101080/6191987)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible by using [PowerPoint Online](https://office.live.com/start/PowerPoint.aspx)

Use the below link to know more about how to embed a PPT to a web page

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/embed-a-presentation-in-a-web-page-or-blog-19668a1d-2299-4af3-91e1-ae57af723a60

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it display only 1 presentation at a time i need to copy the iframe code and display it again. I want to achieve is there is a insert file button on my page and after i insert it display the powerpoint on my page.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [GroupDocs.Viewer](https://products.groupdocs.com/viewer/) API that allows you to render the PowerPoint Presentations in the form that can be easily displayed in your web application.

The API provides 2 rendering modes: HTML-based rendering (to render pages/slides as HTML pages) and Image-based rendering (to render pages/slides as images). You can then easily embed the rendered HTML pages or images in your web application to display the presentation.

**Using C#**

```
ViewerConfig config = new ViewerConfig();
config.StoragePath = "D:\\storage\\";

// Create HTML handler (or ViewerImageHandler for rendering document as image)
ViewerHtmlHandler htmlHandler = new ViewerHtmlHandler(config);

// Guid implies that unique document name 
string guid = "sample.pptx";

// Get document pages in html form
List<PageHtml> pages = htmlHandler.GetPages(guid);

// Or Get document pages in image form using image handler
//List<PageImage> pages = imageHandler.GetPages(guid);

foreach (PageHtml page in pages)
{
    // Get HTML content of each page using page.HtmlContent
}
```

**Using Java**

```
// Setup GroupDocs.Viewer config
ViewerConfig config = new ViewerConfig();
// Set storage path
config.setStoragePath("D:\\storage\\");

// Create HTML handler (or ViewerImageHandler for rendering document as image)
ViewerHtmlHandler htmlHandler = new ViewerHtmlHandler(config);

String guid = "Sample.pptx"

// Get document pages in HTML form
List<PageHtml> pages = htmlHandler.getPages(guid);

for (PageHtml page : pages) {
     // Get HTML content of each page using page.getHtmlContent
}
```

*Disclosure: I work as a Developer Evangelist at GroupDocs.*