# Embed local Powerpoint PPT/PPTX in page

Tags: html, powerpoint, embed

I am trying to embed user-uploaded Powerpoint files (`.ppt` or `.pptx`).

On a company intranet, users can upload presentations and on a separate page other users can view them. As the volume will be high, I cannot use a method that requires manual configuration of each presentation (such as OneDrive embed, SlideShare etc).

The solutions I have found (a few are listed below) only accommodate web-accessible files; this does not work for me, as the files are not accessible outside of a company intranet.

- [Embed a PowerPoint presentation into HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855/embed-a-powerpoint-presentation-into-html) (`iframe` using `docs.google.com/gview`; does not work)
- [Embed a Powerpoint in a Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101080/embed-a-powerpoint-in-a-web-page) (`iframe` using `view.officeapps.live`; does not work)

Is there a solution or library that allows for embedding PowerPoint presentations that are uploaded to a local server directory?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate solution, you can convert PPT/PPTX to JPG/SVG images and display them with [revealjs](https://revealjs.com/). See the source code [here](https://github.com/aspose-slides/Aspose.Slides-for-.NET/blob/master/Demos/Aspose.Slides.Web/Views/Slides/Slideshow.cshtml) and working demo app [here](https://products.aspose.app/slides/viewer).

PS. I am working as SW developer at Aspose.