# How to display PPT in browser?

Tags: javascript, powerpoint

I want to show a PPT in the browser.

*Note*: We cannot use Google Drive or any public platform as the data privacy needs to be maintained.

I have tried using various plugins and could not solve the problem. Does anyone know a good solution?

Comment: Have you checked [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48190902) ?

Comment: Which plugins did you try and what went wrong? There's no point in us going over the same ground again

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.ispringsolutions.com/

They have tools that convert PPT to HTML5, but unlike every competitor I've tried, they don't require you to upload your sensitive PPTX files into the cloud. The software runs on your local machine and spits out code that you can host on your company's server with all the proper cybersecurity protections that are just a reality for any enterprise larger than a small startup.