# Is it possible to render a ppt in react and track the current slide number of the ppt?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, powerpoint, slideshow

I am working on a MERN stack project where a ppt needs to be displayed on the browser and the slide number that the user is on needs to be tracked. Is their a way possible to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed a Powerpoint in a Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101080/embed-a-powerpoint-in-a-web-page)

Comment: I can view the ppt using that solution but I also want to track what slide number is the user currently on.