# How can I best host PowerPoint slides on a web side, interleaved with native HTML content?

Tags: content-management-system, integration, embedded-control

Many of my users prepare training presentations using PowerPoint. My training app presents content in a simple chapter-questions chapter-questions format, where a course module has many chapters, and each chapter is basically a web page for content, and a collection of questions or exercises for that content. I manage the questions individually, i.e. each question is it's own 'document', versus one content document and one questions document per chapter.

I need to offer some kind of import from PowerPoint which will allow a course author to break the PowerPoint presentation into chapters, i.e. groups of slides, and create a new set of question documents, basically as HTML text, so the flow of a course module is e.g.

```
chapter 1 intro - html
chapter 1 content - ppt
chapter 1 question html
chapter 1 question html
```

I realise I could convert the content PowerPoint to HTML, and treat the whole course as native content, but my users are much more familiar with PowerPoint as their content editor, versus *ckeditor* and my utilities. I want to only require the user to author their questions usign my editors, and then just manage the ppt content.

How can I go about this? I realise MS probably has something for hosting ppt content in web pages, and that there may be more open tools for this as well, but the latter isn't a requirement. A dependency on an MS tool, just not PowerPoint itself, is something I'm happy with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft does support an embed option](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint/embed-a-powerpoint-presentation-on-a-webpage-FX102602487.aspx), but you have to own a skydrive account for it to work.

Outside of MS [scribd](http://www.scribd.com/) and [docstoc](http://www.docstoc.com/) also enable you to share powerpoint slides - you can find some more ideas on our sister site [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855/embed-a-powerpoint-presentation-into-html)

IMHO Scribd is the best of the bunch.

Answer (score 2):

You can't embed Powerpoint files directly in an HTML document, but you can do things like pipe it through the [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer), which provides an embedding option. (It doesn't say so up front, but you'll see the code once you import the PPT. If you're going through a CMS, it should be simple enough to have the client upload the PPT files to the site, with you then constructing the necessary URLs via templating.

[Slideshare](http://help.slideshare.com/entries/57490-is-there-any-presentation-format-that-works-better-than-others), and other similar services, also allow for uploading Powerpoint files to them; you could set up and account and just set everything to private.

Comment: I was supprised Su' but MS do allow this via Skydrive http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint/embed-a-powerpoint-presentation-on-a-webpage-FX102602487.aspx

Comment: Well, I primarly meant as in pulling the actual source file directly, eg. images. What you're describing isn't ultimately different from the options I mentioned, although I didn't know about the Skydrive option, which could be definitely be seen as a bonus if someone's workflow is particularly tied to Microsoft's products. It might also just do a better job overall of interpreting the PPT files, since it *is* their own format.

Answer (score 0):

Web Browsers do not render Powerpoint Files, but if you still want the animation you can follow Su's answer above and or use the jQuery Presentation Plugin...

http://www.viget.com/inspire/jquery-presentation-plugin/