# Embedding a powerpoint ppt into a html page

Tags: embed, powerpoint

I want to embed a powerpoint into a webpage.

I can't use any third party solutions like Google docs, DocStoc, Slideshare etc.

Is there any package that I can download, put on my website, pass through the file or file location and then it generate an embedded ppt? I can't find anything that isnt third party/another website to go through.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[iSpringsolutions](http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ppt-to-html5) would be a great choice to convert the file to HTML for embedding.

If you want to embed the file without uploading to other sites,then google docs would be the choice. The fact is you don't have to upload it to google docs to take advantage of their embed service. It has already been answered here-https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694704/3284379

This is the syntax-

```html
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.yourwebsite.com/powerpoint.ppt&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. iSpringsolutions seems alright and could do the job, but seems very expensive. Also, as I said in the question I cannot use third party solutions like Google Docs.