# How to show a PPT in xhtml page and put actions on it to control like next page previous page..etc,.FYI I am using JSF framework

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml, powerpoint, doc

How to show a PPT in xhtml page and put actions on it to control like next page previous page..etc,.FYI I am using JSF framework.

Any kind of reply is appreciable.

Are there any posibilities using the Primefaces

thanks in advance,
SRINI

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the `<p:media>` component.

You can check it out at the Primefaces showcase: 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml

**Edit:**

Sorry i read PDF instead of PPT. Have you tried looking at this post? 
[Embed a PowerPoint presentation into HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855/embed-a-powerpoint-presentation-into-html)