# How to Embed powerpoint in html

Tags: html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("ppt.swf", "ppt", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
 </script>
```

How can I embed a presentation in my webpage,

Thanks,

Comment: my answer useful or not? thanks

Comment: But ispring pro is not open source.If Trial version is completed means will it work in website.

Comment: if my answer useful means, please accepted.. thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed a PowerPoint presentation into HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855/embed-a-powerpoint-presentation-into-html)