# Force hyperlink in local html file to open associated application instead of downloading

Tags: html, windows, url, hyperlink, associated-application

I have local toc-kind-of html file which has a hyperlink to local ppt file located in the path relative to the directory in which this html file is located. When I open the html file in browser and click on it, instead of opening that local file in Power point application, that file is being again downloaded to my default "Download" folder. In other words since the file is local, it is being copied from current directory to "Download" folder". Since the ppt is local I wanted the link to open in Power point application when I clicked it. Is there any changes to this html file or browser settings needed? The html snipped is below:

```
<tr>
    <td height="18" style="width: 485px"><font color="#0000FF"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </b></font><a href="Sample%20Workshop/Sample-Workshops.ppt"><font color="#0000FF"><b>Training Workshops</b></font></a> <font size="1">(ppt)</font></td>
</tr>
```

OS: Windows 10

Browser: New Microsoft Edge

Answer (score 0):

make a folder where your HTML and CSS files exist and paste your ppt then link it

Comment: you mean both html and ppt must be in same folder?

Comment: check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855/embed-a-powerpoint-presentation-into-html

Comment: that deals with opening ppt online. My ppt is offline(local). I just want to open ppt with installed power point application when clicked.

Comment: can I see the whole code, along with file structure