# how to embed PowerPoint presentation with audio on a webpage?

Tags: html5-canvas, powerpoint, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am building a mobile friendly website.
there I need to embed a PowerPoint presentation with an automatically playing audio file.
I used following iframe code generated by PowerPoint itself
& one suggestion from [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855/embed-a-powerpoint-presentation-into-html)

```
<iframe src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;authkey=xxxxxxxxx-egw&amp;em=2&amp;wdAr=1.7777777777777777" width="610px" height="367px" frameborder="0">This is an embedded <a target="_blank" href="https://office.com">Microsoft Office</a> presentation, powered by <a target="_blank" href="https://office.com/webapps">Office</a>.</iframe>
```

this work properly on chrome & edge.
but when i try to open it with my mobile phone (safari for iPhone) audios do not play automatically.
i have to press the button.
is there any other way i can achieve this goal?

Comment: This is a known problem with Safari. You'll have to do some browser-sniffing and display a message to Safari users to try a different browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently PowerPoint web embed do not support audio auto play.
use a SCORM authorizing tool to convert ppt files in to a HTML package.
[SCORM Software Tools](https://www.ispringsolutions.com/blog/scorm-software)