# Embedding documents from static folder in Django

Tags: html, django, django-staticfiles

I am not expert in Django, but I am doing a web site where I would like to embed a ppt, which is saved into the static folder. The code of the html is:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <iframe src="{% static 'ppt/pptexample.pptx' %}" style="width:800px; height:600px;" frameborder="0"/>
{% endblock %}
```

When I load the site, the ppt is perfectly downloaded, but I would like to visualise it online. Then, I have tried to add *`embedded=true`*, that is to say *`{% static 'ppt/pptexample.pptx' %}&embedded=true`*, which did not work. The error message is:

*`ppt\pptexample.pptx&embedded=true' could not be found`*

Debug mode states that **Request URL** is:

*`http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/ppt/pptexample.pptx&embedded%3Dtrue`*

Could you recommend me or letting me know how to embed such a PowerPoint document in the Web?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `which did not work` please elaborate the situation: error message, static file url works but iframe not rendered?

Comment: I don't feel it's a django issues (as far as the little code you shown) but more an html issue. You can use google doc to render a dynamic presentation in your html file
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855/embed-a-powerpoint-presentation-into-html#:~:text=92,from%20your%20page%3A

Comment: I think by iframe does not render **pptx** becaues it's not native to browser you can use [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) tag to render it

Comment: Thanks for the answers, indeed, I finally uploaded the ppts into a OneDrive account and, then, I shared it. Thanks all for your comments.